# How to start an activity from the onFinish method of a countdown?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm kind of new to Android development and I encounter a problem here.

I want to launch an activity (another Class) when my countdown is over.

Edit:

Eclipse is telling me the code won't work, underlining part of my code in red.

The problem doesn't come from the Manifesto or such, I just can't figure out how to implement the call of my other activity.

/Edit

Here is my code:

```
public static void launch_countdown(final TextView tv1){
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             tv1.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             /* I want to launch my Activity here */
         }
    }.start();
}
```

So basically, what should I replace my comment by ?

PS: I made some research but it doesn't seem to work in my situation:

[How to call an activity from a CountDownTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147609/how-to-call-an-activity-from-a-countdowntimer)

[Android finish Activity and start another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599955/android-finish-activity-and-start-another-one)

[How to start an activity upon the completion of a timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064744/how-to-start-an-activity-upon-the-completion-of-a-timer)

Comment: Explain how it doesn't work. You can just put an `Intent` there to start the new `Activity`

Comment: What part of the code is underlined in red? What's the error message for the red underline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating this `CountdownTimer` inside an activity, you should be able to do this:

```
public void onFinish() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OtherActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish(); // if you want this activity to go away
}
```

(If you like, you can replace `getApplicationContext()` with `CurrentActivity.this`. You cannot use a bare `this` because that refers to current instance of the anonymous `CountDownTimer` subclass to which `onFinish()` belongs.)

If this code is in some other class, you'll need access to a `Context` for the first argument. For instance, you could use `tv1.getContext()`.

Alternatively, you can use one of the other `Intent` constructors that does not require a `Context`. See the [API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for more info.